# Not all Google Apps in SuperNexus Rom on Galaxy S3

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, custom-roms, google-apps

I installed the SuperNexus 2.0 Build 4 ROM on my Galaxy S3 (i9300) last weekend. I also installed the gapps-jb-20130301-signed.zip to install the Google apps. However, that does not seem to have worked. I do not have YouTube or Google Maps. I do have Gmail however.

How can I install the Google Maps and Youtube applications?

Comment: That describes a fact -- but what is your question?

Comment: You were right, I edited the question.

Comment: Youtube and GMaps should come with the GApps package usually. But with the "core apps" installed, you could try loading them manually via Google Play (you've got that with the GApps, right?).